# Metro XAML - Where Is LayoutTransform ?

Tags: xaml, custom-controls, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Im authoring some Windows 8 Metro template (custom) controls and there doesnt seem to me any LayoutTransform properties on anything.

this is a real pain, as I want to rotate some text 90 desgrees, but the grid is sizing to the size of the text before the rotation.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this without writing lots of hacks ?

Dean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LayoutTransform was gone in Silverlight too. (IMHO) I guess maybe it was usually overused or abused in WPF causing performance issues, so for better perception of the framework - it was never added to Silverlight and by extension - to WinRT.

There seems to be a workaround for that in the Silverlight Toolkit that should be easy to port - check the [LayoutTransformer control](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74775?ProjectName=silverlight#779405). I have never used it, but it sounds like what you need.

*Edit 2017-04-24

There's a [`LayoutTransformControl`](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/LayoutTransformControl/LayoutTransformControl.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit you could use.

Comment: For me, LayoutTransform is at least as useful as RenderTransform, so Im suprised they took the Silverlight approach. It looks like Im going to have to rip off the LayoutTransformer code from the Silverlight Toolkit to achieve my objective - thanks for the answer and info

Answer (score 8):

I modified the Silverlight toolkit version and published it here

[Layout transform in Windows 8 XAML](http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/)

Comment: It doesn't work. When I copy this code I receive a COMException Error. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. Any ideas.

Comment: Is it possible to use LayoutTransform on Windows Phone? I have tried but stuck with importing Windows.UI.Xaml namespace.

Comment: @Anthony have you checked the Silverlight toolkit version? http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74775#779405

Comment: it was deprecated in favor to Windows Phone Toolkit and WPT doesn't contain LayoutTransform

Comment: @user1131657 Sure you solved it in the meantime, but if anyone else comes accross the HRESULT E_FAIL error - don't forget to include the style igrali has postet below the actual LayoutTransformer class into your project (app.xaml). Fixed it for me.